# Inverting Logical AND Condition

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, if-statement, conditional-operator

I'm working on the following code:

```
// $data has only one dimension AND at least one of its values start with a "@"
if ( (count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
  && (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0) )
{
    // do nothing
}

else
{
    // do something
}
```

The logic of this condition is working just fine, however, I would prefer if I could get rid of the empty `if` block while evaluating the second condition only if the first one yields true - otherwise the `preg_grep()` call will throw the following notice when `$data` has more than one dimension:

> **Notice**: Array to string conversion

I know I could use the error suppression operator or some other *hacky* approaches, but I have the feeling that I'm missing something trivial. Can someone help me out, please?

Comment: `&&` is short-circuit already... isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, obvious way:

```
if (!( (count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
    && (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0)) )
{
    // everything is cool, nothing to do
}

else
{
    // do something
}
```

Second, *correct* way

```
if ((count($data) < count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
 || (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) == 0))
{
    // everything is cool, nothing to do
}

else
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!((count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) && (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0)))
```

{
    // do something
}

Answer (score 2):

```
if (! (
   count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE) && 
   count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0
   )
```

Wrap the entire group of conditions and stick ! at the start. Line breaks are for readability. I removed the unnecessary () around the individual conditions as well.

Comment: Thanks, I use this operator so rarely that sometimes I even forget that it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely clear what you're asking, but I think you want:

```
// $data has only one dimension AND at least one of its values start with a "@"
if (!((count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE))
  && (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0)))
{
    // do something
}
```

With this, the block executes if `((count($data) == count($data, COUNT_RECURSIVE)) && (count(preg_grep('~^@~', $data)) > 0))` is false.